# Creating chocolatey packages for plug-ins of "large" applications

Tags: installation, dependencies, nuget, chocolatey, choco

I have a question about using Chocolatey to package plugins for other applications. Say I have a primary application `sample-app`, and a plugin that can be installed for this `sample-app-plugin`.

Technically `sample-app-plugin` depends on `sample-app` as it can't run with out it and must be installed after it. At first I would think I would want to add `sample-app` to the list of dependencies in `sample-app-plugin`. For example, this is how [the plugin packages for keepass](https://community.chocolatey.org/packages?q=tag%3Akeepass) are created.

However, sometimes the parent application is a "major installation". The installer may be hundreds of MB if not a few GB. When users attempt to install a small plug-in they won't be expecting this to trigger a major installation or update of other software on their machine.

So, in this case I would much rather the installation of `sample-app-plugin` simply fail if `sample-app` is not installed. Is there a way to continue to use the built in dependencies feature of Chocolatey/Nuget, but only use this to check if required dependencies are installed but not attempt to actually install them? There's the `--ignoredependencies` option, but as far as I can tell this just ignores the dependencies entirely. Alternatively it would also work if the user is first warned that `sample-app` is about to be installed with an option to cancel.

If there is not a way to do this with actual package dependencies what is the best way to check for existing choco packages in the chocolateyInstall.ps1 file? The first thing that comes to mind is to just check the version in the nuspec file in the expected installation location:

```
$PackageName = "sample-app"
([xml]$xml = Get-Content $env:ChocolateyInstall\lib\$PackageName\$PackageName.nuspec).package.metadata.version
```

Answer (score 1):

If you add `sample-app` as a dependency of `sample-app-plugin` then it will only be installed if it's not already installed. If you don't add the installer for `sample-app` to the `sample-app` package, but instead download it from somewhere internal as package of the package installation, then you're only downloading the package itself which will be around 5k.

The other way to do this is adding a check inside the `sample-app-plugin` package that `throw`'s an error if `sample-app` is not installed.

You can't do this simply with dependencies *yet*.

(I'm the maintainer of the `keepass` packages).

Comment: How would you check for and existing sample-app installation inside sample-app-plugin? Is my example of reading the nuspec files directly a good idea, or is there some other utility that makes this easier. It's my understanding that is a bad idea to run choco commands within a package.